# Spark LogisticRegression example does not classify test data

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

The [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-guide.html#example-pipeline) contains the following example for logistic regression:

```py
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
LabeledDocument = Row("id", "text", "label")
training = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (0L, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
    (1L, "b d", 0.0),
    (2L, "spark f g h", 1.0),
    (3L, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0)], ["id", "text", "label"])

# Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of tree stages: tokenizer, hashingTF, and lr.
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(), outputCol="features")
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, lr])

# Fit the pipeline to training documents.
model = pipeline.fit(training)

# Prepare test documents, which are unlabeled (id, text) tuples.
test = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (4L, "spark i j k"),
    (5L, "l m n"),
    (6L, "mapreduce spark"),
    (7L, "apache hadoop")], ["id", "text"])

# Make predictions on test documents and print columns of interest.
prediction = model.transform(test)
selected = prediction.select("id", "text", "prediction")
for row in selected.collect():
    print(row)
```

Because rows `0L` and `2L` are labeled as 1.0, I was expecting rows `4L` and `6L` to be predicted as 1.0 as well.  However, this is the output I receive:

```py
Row(id=4, text=u'spark i j k', prediction=0.0)
Row(id=5, text=u'l m n', prediction=0.0)
Row(id=6, text=u'mapreduce spark', prediction=0.0)
Row(id=7, text=u'apache hadoop', prediction=0.0)
```

Can anyone let me know why no rows were predicted to be 1.0?

Comment: Accuracy can't be 100% otherwise it will definitively be overfitting.

Comment: @eliasah as an example, I was assuming that it would predict something.  I guess that assumption is incorrect?

Comment: the example is actually bad. try with simple input if you are looking for an example

Comment: @eliasah thanks.  Specifically how is the sample bad?  Not enough data?

Comment: to be quite honest it's bit broad too answer here. but mainly you'd need to look to your tfidf vector and compare it's features to the test tfidf vector